# Configure how long requests are displayed in CertSrv web enrollment

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, certificate-authority, web, ad-certificate-services

I have a Win2008R2 enterprise CA in ADCS and the certificate template is set to ask CA administrator to issue or deny the request. By default, when the user submits the requests through web enrollment, the request is set as pending but the list of pending requests per user is displayed for about a week before the request disappears from the user's pending list. The request is still visible through the MMC Snap in but not in the Web Enrollment UI. Even if the request is issued, the certificate is no longer visible in the user's Web UI.

Is there  a way to configure this expiration time for requests made through web enrollment?

Answer (score 0):

Followed these instructions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381929(v=vs.85).aspx

This can be configured by editing the file `\WindowsDirectory\System32\Certsrv\Certdat.inc` and changing the variable `nPendingTimeoutDays`